Apparent paradox in FM modulation related to Bessel Series
In electronic music there is a synthesis technique that people call "FM synthesis", FM standing for Frequency Modulation. This technique became hugely popular in the 80's with the advent of the Yamaha DX7 synth which led to innumerable charts hits.
I'm trying to better understand how it's working and came to an apparent paradox.
Actually the FM synthesis implemented is not a frequency modulation but a phase modulation :
The audio signal has the following form:
$y(t)= A⋅sin(\omega_c t + I⋅sin(\omega_m t))$
Where :

t is the time
$\omega_c = 2π f_c$ , $f_c$ being the frequency of the carrier function, here a simple sine function  $A⋅sin(\omega_c t)$
$\omega_m = 2π f_m$ , $f_m$ being the frequency of the modulation function, here, also a simple sine function  $I⋅sin(\omega_m t)$
I is the intensity of the modulation
A is the max amplitude

It's a theorem that y(t) can be written as an infinite sum of Bessel functions :
$y(t)= A⋅sin(\omega_c t + I⋅sin(\omega_m t)) = A⋅\sum_{n=-∞}^{∞} J_n (I)⋅sin((\omega_c +n⋅\omega_m)t)$

$J_n(I)$ being the Bessel function of order n

Now it becomes interesting : this gives us the spectrum of the audio signal, $J_n(I)$ is the amplitude of frequency $(\omega_c +n⋅\omega_m)t$
So we now have a way to determine what would be the spectrum of the FM modulation of a sine signal, given the ratio $R=\frac{\omega_m}{\omega_c}$
For example, if we have R = 1, the spectrum contains all the harmonics of the fundamental :$f_c, 2f_c, 3f_c, 4f_c, 5f_c$...
As you surely know, in music if $f_c$ is the fundamental, $2f_c$ is the octave, $3f_c$ is the fifth (quinte), $4f_c$ the octave again, $5f_c$ the third etc... And musicians can recognise by hear these intervals
This was all the objective of this introduction :  providing a method to know a priori what would be the effect of a modulation on a signal, given the R ratio
We have seen R = 1
Now with the paradox, for R = 3
We have  $y(t)= A \sum_{n=-∞}^{∞}J_n (I)⋅sin((\omega_c +n⋅3⋅\omega_c)t)$
So the harmonics should be 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
And we know from the Fourier theorem that this decomposition is unique;
In other words there is no 2 harmonic (octave). (Proposition A)
But...
If you put your signal into a spectrogram, you find that:
Clearly 3 harmonics, of order 1, 2 , 4.

And also if you have a small modulation amplitude I, you can demonstrate it using a Taylor development
$y(t)= A⋅sin(\omega_c t + I ⋅ sin(3\omega_c t)) ≈ A⋅sin(\omega_c t)+ A⋅I ⋅ cos(\omega_c t) ⋅ sin(3\omega_c t)$
We have $cos(\omega_c t) ⋅ sin(3\omega_c t)= [sin(4\omega_c t) − sin(2\omega_c t)] / 2$
Hence
$y(t) ≈ A⋅sin(\omega_c t)+2A⋅I [sin(4\omega_c t)−sin(2\omega_c t)]$
We have confirmed the experimentation and proven that for I small, there are 3 harmonics including the octave. (Proposition B)
Which is contradictory with the previous result (A), hence the paradox
My intuition is that B is misleading.
The infinite sum of Bessel functions might approximate a 2 harmonic, creating the illusion there is an harmonic of rank 2, which actually does not exist, and this would solve the paradox. However, I  do not have the courage to prove it. Maybe someone would here.
But the main point, which brought me here,  is that a Fourier transformation might not give you a clear idea of the practical aspect of a spectrogram, and I find it very confusing.
EDIT :
As per the answers received, the phase modulation of a carrier of frequency $f_c$ by a modulation function of amplitude I and frequency $f_m = R f_c$ produces a spectrum with peaks of value:

$J_0(I)$ at $f=f_c$,
$J_n(I)$ at $f=f_c . (1+nR)$ and $f=f_c . (nR -1)$ for $n≥1/R$.
If  $0<R<1$, additional peaks are found below the carrier at $f=f_c . (1-nR)$ for $n<1/R$.

In the rare case where $R=2/p$, $p$ integer, then the peak at $f=f_c . (1 + nR)$ is $J_n + J_{n+p}$

Please write your formulas using MathJax.

Hint: What is $\omega_c+n, 3, \omega_c$ for $n=-1$?

^^. I guess you're smarter than chatgpt and me in the middle of the night. Thanks

As hinted by Steven Clark, n can be negative in the Bessel series, and so, the Bessel series and the $J_n(I)$ coefficients do not directly represent the value expected in the spectrogram, where an harmonic has per definition a positive rank order. Sorry for the embarrassment.

Since $$J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^n J_n(x),,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ and $$\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$$ for $n=-1$ one has $$J_n(I), \sin((\omega_c+n 3 \omega_c) t)=J_1(I) \sin (2 \omega_c t)$$ so clearly the octave is expected in the spectrum.

I got it. My point is that I was confused the Bessel function did not directly give me the Fourrier coefficients. See my edited question for clarification.
